# Pipe output to a command while still writing to stdout

Tags: bash, pipe, tee

I have a command that writes to stdout, let's say it's `ls`. I want to pipe its output to a program `foo`, while still writing that output to stdout.

I looked into `tee`, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to pipe to a program instead of writing to a file.